# How to access data inside child inside another child from Firebase in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, json, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from Firebase. I made my own JSON file and validate it using online JSON validator and is valid. So I upload it in the database section of my JSON file.

It looks something like this:

```
fir-practice-8c94a

        recipes
          0
            Morning
               Breakfast
                   object
                   object
                   object
                   object
                   object

          1
            Afternoon
                 Lunch
                   object
                   object
                   object
                   object
                   object
```

This is how does look my Firebase Database.
I have parent recipes then two objects, inside these objects I have another child then another and many objects.

I am not sure if I over complicated my JSON. I wanted to be a little more organized.

But now I am not sure how to event access these child that is inside another child? The objects after Breakfast and Lunch are the recipes.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What have you tried? Can you provide some code or pseudocode illustrating your problem?

Comment: Sadly not, i don't have anything, i don't even know how to start. I want to know how to access child that is nested in another child. Example, i want to display Morning and Evening only. Or, do access objects inside morning and evening.